# Joomla regex in logger

Tags: php, regex, logging, joomla

can someone explain what is happening in the following lines.

```
JLog::addLogger(array('text_file' => 'log.php'), JLog::INFO);
JLog::add('Test', JLog::INFO, '((?:test<[a-zA-Z][^>]*>\s*){0,7})');


//logger output :: testa-za-zs07
```

1. What is happening in the piece `((?:test<[a-zA-Z][^>]*>\s*){0,7})`?
2. Why joomla logger is not giving / logging the exact string as is `((?:test<[a-zA-Z][^>]*>\s*){0,7})`?
3. Can some one explain each piece of `((?:test<[a-zA-Z][^>]*>\s*){0,7})`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`((?:test<[a-zA-Z][^>]*>\s*){0,7})` is a regular expression. Here is an explanation of what this expression means: http://regex101.com/r/dZ8sA1

If it still is not clear after you've read that link, just ask and I'll try to explain further.

Comment: Wow. Its really too good. I was looking for such decoder. I have bookmarked the same. I tried to test the following http://regex101.com/r/lQ0fG7. It gives me error. I made this regular expression to match {/mylink}. But getting validation erro. Please help.

Comment: Just escape the forward slash (/).

Answer (score 0):

This is a regular expression.

```
((?:test<[a-zA-Z][^>]*>\s*){0,7})
```

This is one big capturing group.

`?:` means non-capturing group for that parentheses.

`[a-zA-Z]` means one character a-z or A-Z.

`[^>]*` means zero or more everything except ">".

`\s*` means zero or more space sign (tab, space etc.).

`{0,7}` means from 0 to 7 repeats

So, basically whole pattern means:

Look for test, then < sign, then one sign a-zA-Z, then zero or more sign except >, then > sign, then optional space. And look for this from 0 to 7 repeats. So it looks for a tag preceeded by a 'test' word.

Here you have some [example](http://regexr.com?31so9). It matches only first 7 test's